# Always on top Python script in MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6

I have python script, it showing gif in window and brings this window to top over all other opened windows (or the windows which will be opened in future). It works perfectly in Windows operation system, but in MacOS if I'm watching video in full screen or have some application in full screen when this script runs, the video is exitting from full screen and the window also exitting from full screen. And I see 2 windows next to each other, but I want one on top of the other. If the other windows not in full mode it's OK, the problem only with full mode. Here is the very simple Python script:

```py
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import time
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class LoadingGif(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 200)
        base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        imagePath = os.path.join(base_path, "earth.gif")

        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie(imagePath)
        self.movie.setScaledSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 200, 200))
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.label.mousePressEvent = self.CloseWindow
        self.movie.start()
        
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

    def CloseWindow(self, event):
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    time.sleep(5)

    window = LoadingGif()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I've tried to add some WindowFlag attributes, but I didn't found the right one.

I'll be very appreciated for any help or hint!

Comment: I have no knowledge about the current status of macOS window management (and they tend to change lots of important aspects between versions, completely disregarding consistency). But, I can only assume that you cannot do that. Depending on the full screen "mode" and OS version/user configuration, either your window will always be under any other full screen window, or they will eventually exit full screen. Note: you should never use blocking functions in GUI environments; remove that `time.sleep()` and replace the next to last line with `QTimer.singleShot(5000, window.show)`.

Comment: Thank you for your note, actually this script is the part of big project, so this time.sleep function is added only for the testing.

Comment: I understand that, but due to the way QApplication has to deal with system events and its own, doing it for testing may potentially give you different results, and that's exactly based on what you *actually* do there in your real program.

Comment: The issue you're encountering on macOS is due to the way fullscreen applications handle window activation. When a fullscreen application is active, it prevents other windows from being brought to the front, including those with the `WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag set. This behaviour is intended to ensure that users can focus on the full-screen application without distractions from other windows.

Comment: I'm fully understand that, but what about system messages? Are they behave the same way?

Comment: Research more, choose frameworks, try to implement a prototype and ask a specific question. For example, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34618518/1186624), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5619466/1186624), and [this](https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).